# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I have an array with the names of the images in the form of strings, I want to transform it into an array of images and I getting this error, what I did wrong?

```
 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

My code:

```
NSString * immagini = self.chinaTable.images; //unique string

NSArray * arrayImages = [immagini componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]; 
NSLog(@"The images: %@", arrayImages);// here are strings

/*The images: (
"ArchUrb_PortaGenova1.jpg",
"ArchUrb_PortaGenova2.jpg",
"ArchUrb_PortaGenova3.jpg",
"ArchUrb_PortaGenova4.jpg"
)*/

NSMutableArray * mutableImages =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:20];

for (id obj in arrayImages){

/*The images: (
"ArchUrb_PortaGenova1.jpg",
"ArchUrb_PortaGenova2.jpg",
"ArchUrb_PortaGenova3.jpg",
"ArchUrb_PortaGenova4.jpg"
)*/


 [mutableImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:obj]];//here comes the error
  NSLog(@"The array mutable is è %@", mutableImages);
}
NSLog(@"The array of images %@", mutableImages);

self.viewImages.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableImages];

self.viewImages.animationDuration =3;
self.viewImages.animationRepeatCount= 0;
[self.viewImages startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 3):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` returns `nil` if it can't find the requested image in your app bundle.

Add missing image to your project, or add an `if` before adding image to array, like this:

```
for (id obj in arrayImages){
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:obj];
    if (image != nil)
    {
        [mutableImages addObject:image];
    }
    NSLog(@"The array mutable is è %@", mutableImages);
}
```

Comment: Why do not it find? The images are all in the bundle with the correct name

Comment: @user1747321 show your `NSString * immagini` contents, please.

Comment: The individual images are nil even if the array is full

Comment: Your filenames seems right to me. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project, make sure the image is actually in your project and the target for images is checked by clicking on the file and selecting the target it belongs to. Also, note that filenames are case-sensitive.

Comment: maybe you can try to use PNGs instead of JPGs, iOS compresses them for you, so there will be little to no app size difference.

Comment: Where I use the PNG? I cleaning and rebuilding the project but the error is the same. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code segment as follows

```
for (id obj in arrayImages){

    UIImage *image  = [UIImage imageNamed:obj];
    if ( image ) {
       [mutableImages addObject:image];
       NSLog(@"The array mutable is è %@", mutableImages);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to the question: [Exception with insertObject:atIndex: on iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891858/exception-with-insertobjectatindex-on-ios6/12892460#12892460). So please read it to find your solution.