# NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uncaught-exception

After a lot of search, and tries with some solutions on stackoverflow, i didn't find any answer which could solve my error :
I have a UIViewcontroller, who's name is WorldViewController. In this UIViewcontroller, i had init some UIViews. I want to modificate some variables which depends of WorldViewController from some UIViews. And now that i put those lines :

```
WorldViewController * World = [[WorldViewController alloc] init];
```

it gives me :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

So, how to fix it ? Could it comes from the fact that WorldViewController is running ? And so, how to fix it ?

Edit : init method of my viewcontroller

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        World1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
        [World1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:World1];
        [World1 release];

        [self.view addSubview:ViewPig];
        [self.view addSubview:level1view];
        [self.view addSubview:level2view];
        [self.view addSubview:LoadView];
        [LoadView AnimPigLoadingWith:PigChargement];
        [LoadView AppearLabelLoading];
        [self.view addSubview:FondPauseGrise];
        [self.view addSubview:FondPause];
        [self.view addSubview:BoutonResume];
        [self.view addSubview:BoutonHome];
        [self performSelector:@selector(Chargement) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
        [self performSelector:@selector(ViewAppears) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.5+2.5];
        [self performSelector:@selector(LabelPrevientDepartWithImage:) withObject:Trois afterDelay:9];
        [self performSelector:@selector(LabelPrevientDepartWithImage:) withObject:Deux afterDelay:10];
        [self performSelector:@selector(LabelPrevientDepartWithImage:) withObject:Un afterDelay:11];
        [self performSelector:@selector(LabelPrevientDepartWithImage:) withObject:Go afterDelay:12];
        [self performSelector:@selector(Lancement) withObject:nil afterDelay:(3)];
        [self performSelector:@selector(GestionMaps) withObject:nil afterDelay:(11+2)];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: There is not enough code provided.  We need to see some of the implementation of the init method of `WorldViewController`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't listed enough code in your question to definitely show where you're making an error.

Look in your code for any lines that say "`insertObject:atIndex:`".  The object you're inserting is apparently nil.

If you can't find this line, [add a symbolic breakpoint on the symbol "`[NSArray insertObject:atIndex:]`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892460/981049) (click the link to see specific instructions in an answer of a closely related question to yours) and see if you can break on it right before the crash happens.

Comment: The problem is, i don't have any "insertObject:atIndex:" in my code, in my viewcontroller or uiview, and this error occured only when i add WorldViewController * World = [[WorldViewController alloc] init];

Comment: what happens when you add the symbolic breakpoint?  where does it stop the debugger?

Comment: Just before this line : WorldViewController * World = [[WorldViewController alloc] init];    This line fails, i don't know why

Comment: what's going on inside your WorldViewController `init` function?

Comment: [self.view addSubview:myUIView]; and some methods are called

Comment: I wonder if "`myUIView`" is null or not instantiated or loaded yet?  You should check that.

Comment: Nop, because my viewcontroller is open, and some methods of my UIView are running, it's just this line i don't know how to fix it :/

Comment: Edit your question to show the code that appears in your "`init`" method.

Comment: try: if(myUIView != nill){[self.view addSubview:myUIView]}

Comment: I've edit. Casilic, it's not working. My uiview is level1view

Comment: you are adding it to it's own view? [self.view addSubview:World1];

Comment: World1 is a UIView on the view controller

Comment: Are you call init or [[WorldViewController alloc] initWithNibName:  bundle:];?

Comment: any solutions ? I am stuck on the same issue and my condition is same as well. Help please.

Comment: @AnkitMehta look at what I suggested in my solution and see if it helps you out as well.

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar problem. My mistake was in not marking the view that I was trying to load as the initial view controller. My guess is that the there was no initial view controller to add to the array and hence the object was nil. I'm not sure how good this is at answering your question but it worked for me.

[image]