# IOS Application Terminating at main file itself NSException

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
2015-09-21 10:57:48.696 Kip Up[4707:140538] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00ce6746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x005b9a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00b9bce1 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 881
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00b9b941 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 65
    4   UIKit                               0x0134bc3b -[UIView(UIViewGestures) addGestureRecognizer:] + 210
    5   Kip Up                              0x000c0c1e -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 414
    6   UIKit                               0x0141dd54 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 771
    7   UIKit                               0x0141e045 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x0130fe35 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x013102fc -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 287
    10  UIKit                               0x013105f8 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    11  UIKit                               0x0131e966 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 80
    12  UIKit                               0x012b3e88 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3217
    13  UIKit                               0x012b73d2 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639
    14  UIKit                               0x012d08ee __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
    15  UIKit                               0x012b5ffa -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x04490c9e __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    17  FrontBoardServices                  0x0449072f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x044a2d7c __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 30
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00c08050 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00bfd963 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00bfd7bb __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00bfca5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00bfc88b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  UIKit                               0x012b59b2 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
    25  UIKit                               0x012b90b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    26  Kip Up                              0x000c229a main + 138
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x03278ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Perhaps this answer is relevant? : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27459488/1455770

Comment: It always crashes in the main file :'(

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your root view controller `UIViewController` connections are intact. It usually happens due to broken link on the Interface Builder. If you are using Storyboards, make sure you haven't hooked up duplicate referencing outlets. Also ensure that you are importing `AppDelegate.h`.

Again there could be n number of reason for this crash. Please use exception or symbolic break point to come to a conclusion.

Comment: not above any Issues

https://www.facebook.com/shashankrana29

this is my facebook account link

Comment: all header files are included
no connections are hooked up
no duplicate outlets are there
initial view controller is also set
drop one message on fb link i can provide remote access to solve my problem.

Comment: If you can share github link to your project that will be great. I don't want to take remote access and work.