# Where do you add a symbolic breakpoint in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I'm trying to add a symbolic breakpoint but Cmd+6 is not doing anything and the `+` is no where to be found. Trying to follow this: [Exception with insertObject:atIndex: on iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891858/exception-with-insertobjectatindex-on-ios6/12892460#12892460)

Here is what my screen looks like where my breakpoint normally appear:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the menu selection Debug -> Breakpoints -> Create Symbolic Breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add those breakpoints in the Debug Area, that's not the correct area. You have to do it in the navigator area (i.e. the right side bar). Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> to show the breakpoint navigator.

[image]